# Is there anyway automatically select whole text inside SelectableText when widget build or after initState?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to automatically select whole text inside SelectableText after widget built or initState run.

Here is the SelectableText widget Code:

```
SelectableText(
    widget.text,
    contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
        final List<ContextMenuButtonItem> contextMenuButtonItem = [
            ContextMenuButtonItem(
                label: 'Copy',
                onPressed: () async {
                    editableTextState.copySelection(SelectionChangedCause.toolbar);
                },
             ),
             ContextMenuButtonItem(
                 label: 'Select All',
                 onPressed: () {
                     editableTextState.selectAll(SelectionChangedCause.tap);
                 },
             ),
         ];
         return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
                    anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
                    buttonItems: contextMenuButtonItem,
         );
    },
)
```

[SelectableText widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q03wf.png)

I tried using TextField, It worked, but toolBar did not show up.

TextEditingController, FocusNode and initState

```
  final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textEditingController.text = widget.text;
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
        _textEditingController.selection = TextSelection(
          baseOffset: 0,
          extentOffset: _textEditingController.text.length,
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

[TextEditingController,FocusNode and initState](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX5g8.png)

TextField widget

```
    TextField(
        controller: _textEditingController,
        maxLines: null,
        readOnly: true,
        autofocus: true,
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
        contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
            final List<ContextMenuButtonItem> contextMenuButtonItem = [
                ContextMenuButtonItem(
                    label: 'Copy',
                    onPressed: () async {
                        editableTextState.copySelection(SelectionChangedCause.toolbar);
                    },
                ),
                ContextMenuButtonItem(
                    label: 'Select All',
                    onPressed: () {
                        editableTextState.selectAll(SelectionChangedCause.tap);
                    },
                ),
            ];
            return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
                anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
                buttonItems: contextMenuButtonItem,
            );
        },
    )
```

[TextField widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJJaf.png)

TextField result:
[TextField result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX2GI.png)

Is there anyway can solve this problem by using SelectableText?

Thanks.